# Indexing data to avoid dual y axes

Tags: r

I would like to normalize two data sets so that they both have a common value at a particular base date.  This would allow me to avoid charting a dual axis plot.

Here is some sample data:

```
x=c(2,5,8,7,9)
y=c(45,56,76,45,89)
w=strptime(20120101:20120105,'%Y%m%d')
z=data.frame(w,x,y)
```

Which returns this:

```
           w x  y
1 2012-01-01 2 45
2 2012-01-02 5 56
3 2012-01-03 8 76
4 2012-01-04 7 45
5 2012-01-05 9 89
```

I would like to normalize x and y on a particular date, let us say 2012-01-03 in the above sample so that on that date both x and y are equal to 100.  Here are my concerns:

1. How do I single out record 3 to get x.Index=100 and y.Index=100?
2. How can I create the percent difference in all other records for x.Index and y.Index from record 3's x and y, respectively?

For question 2 I have something like this `z[-1,'x.Index']=(z[-1,'x']/z[-nrow(z),'x'])*100` but that returns the percent change from the previous record, not from the base record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one version:

```
> x=c(2,5,8,7,9)
> y=c(45,56,76,45,89)
> w=strptime(20120101:20120105,'%Y%m%d')
> z=data.frame(w,x,y)
> z
           w x  y
1 2012-01-01 2 45
2 2012-01-02 5 56
3 2012-01-03 8 76
4 2012-01-04 7 45
5 2012-01-05 9 89
> baseRow <- subset(z, z$w == as.POSIXct("2012-01-03"))
> 
> x.Pct <- (z$x / baseRow$x) - 1
> y.Pct <- (z$y / baseRow$y) - 1
> 
> newDf <- data.frame(w , x = x.Pct, y = y.Pct)
> newDf
           w      x          y
1 2012-01-01 -0.750 -0.4078947
2 2012-01-02 -0.375 -0.2631579
3 2012-01-03  0.000  0.0000000
4 2012-01-04 -0.125 -0.4078947
5 2012-01-05  0.125  0.1710526
```